# How do i fix the gravity body on the unity script C# code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[I am trying to make a game with a friend this error came we have no idea how to fix since we are beginners.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O08EJ.png)

Comment: You have a period where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Also, please include the error here and more about what frameworks you are using, if any.  This way it can be searched and is defined a little better, instead of just linking the question text to an external resource.

Comment: what is frameworks? and when i hover over the "=" is says "identifier expected"

Comment: click on the first sentence for the picture of what i done

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, insert your code snippets as text into your question and not as linked images.

Answer (score 1):

In C#,

```
xxx. = yyy;
```

is not valid.

it would make sense if you have :

```
xxx.aaa = yyy;
```

so the compiler tells you "I'm expecting some *name* after the dot, like aaa". This *name* is called an *indentifier*, hence the error you get.

This would mean : set the property/field named `aaa`of `xxx` with the value of `yyy`

I think you can simply remove the dot.

```
xxx = yyy;
```

(set the value of xxx as yyy)